# No '/etc' Files Created during Apache Installation

Tags: command-line, apache2, make, etc

I have installed Apache using the follow command:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre --enable-so
make
sudo make install
```

Now apache is installed successfully (no error message in terminal), I obviously want to run it. When I browse to `/usr/local/apache2/bin/` and run it using `sudo apachectl start` it does however give me an error message.

```
apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

When I browse to `/etc/` indeed there is no apache2 directory. Why is this and what did I do wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default installation path for configuration files is usually `/usr/local/etc` (but for Apache, it is `/usr/local/apache2/conf`). To change this, you should pass `--sysconfdir=/etc` to the `configure` program.

Since `/usr/local/apache2/sbin` is not in your `$PATH`, you are using the Apache installation from your distribution (which usually resides in `/usr/sbin`). Either specify the full path (`sudo /usr/local/apache2/sbin/apachectl start`) or put the apache2 directory in your PATH before executing. (You could have found out this by running `which apachectl` or `type apachectl`.)

Why are you installing Apache by hand if you don't know what you are doing? I suggest to stick to the distro-packaged version unless you have a very compelling reason not to do so.

More details about configure options:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/configure.html

Comment: Running Apache using `sudo /usr/local/apache2/sbin/apachectl start` it tries to look for the configuration file `httpd.conf` inside the non-existent `/usr/local/apache/conf` directory rather than the existing `/usr/local/apache2/conf` directory.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to run 'make clean' apparently.